# How a maximal ideal is related to unity in a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I need to prove the two statements below:

Given a commutative ring $R$ with unity, if $m$ is a proper ideal in $R$ then: $$m \,\,\text{is maximal } \Leftrightarrow a\in R-m \,\,\text{implies} \,\,Ra+m=R$$ $$ m \,\,\text{is maximal } \Leftrightarrow \forall a\in R-m \,\, \exists\,\, r\in R,\,\, k\in m \,\,\text{such that}\,\, ra+k=1.$$

First it is unclear if by $R-m$ it is meant the complement of $m$ in $R.$ If we suppose that is the case, let m be a maximal ideal (i.e. for all proper ideals $a$ in $R,\,\,$ $m \subset a$ implies $a=m$ ) and $a\in R-m.$ Let $Ra$ be the ideal generated by $a.$ Since $m$ is supposed maximal, it is not contained in $Ra.$ Thus, $\exists \,s \in m$ and $s \notin Ra,\,\, $such that $a+s \in R, $ thus $Ra+m \subset R.$ Is this correct ? So  the inclusion $"\subset "$ is more or less trivial. To prove the other inclusion, $"\supset", \,\,$ let $r\in R, \,a\in R-m$. Since $r\in m \,\,$ will contradict the assumption $a\in R-m,\,$ lets suppose $r\notin m.$ It implies that $r\in R-m.$ Now I am not quite sure what should follow. I am tempting to state that $r$ belongs to the same ideal as $a$ does (since $a\in R-m$). Is this correct ? If it were correct, then I guess eather $r\in Ra$ or $Rr\,\, \cap \,\,Ra\neq \varnothing.$ I dont understand how I could decompose $r$ into two componenets. Also so far I didnt use the maximality of $m.$

Can somebody help me out to correct and finish the proof, and also propose a solution to the second statement. Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, $R-m$ is the complement of $m$.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing a lot more work than you have to. Remember that the sum of ideals is an ideal, that ideals are additive subgroups of $R$, and that they are closed under multiplication with elements of $R$, and the arguments for the first equivalence can be made a lot shorter:

$\implies$: $aR+m$ is an ideal of $R$. It contains $m$ and is strictly larger than $m$ because it also contains $a$. By maximality of $m$, we must therefore have $aR+m=R$.

$\Longleftarrow$ (contrapositive): let $m$ be non-maximal. Then there is a proper ideal $n\subset R$ with $m\subsetneq n$. Let $a\in n-m$ (the complement of $m$ in $n$). Then $aR+m\subseteq n\subsetneq R$.

Comment: Thanks. I dont understand though, why $aR+m\subseteq n.$ Could you say a word on this ? Also how one can obtain the very interesting relation $ra+k=1$ given the maximality of $m$ ?

Comment: @user249018 That's because $a\in n$, so $aR\subseteq n$ (this is one of the defining properties of ideals, after all). Together with $m\subseteq n$, we get $aR+m\subseteq n$. For your other point, that there exist $r\in R, k\in m$ such that $ar + k = 1$, it's a direct consequence of $1\in R = aR+m$, using the definition of sum of ideals.